# Laravel Unique returns only one record

Tags: unique, laravel-5.6

I have a jobs table and operators table.
One operator can have several job records on the jobs table, while a job can only have one operator.

Now i want to get the record of the latest job of all operators with no duplication.

Here's what i used

```
$availableOperators = DB::table('operator')
                ->join('job','operator.OperatorId', '=', 'job.OperatorId')
                ->where('operator.available',1)
                ->orderBy('job.JobId','desc')
                ->get()
                ->unique('job.OperatorId');
```

Without the unique query, i am able to see all the records that satisfy the condition but on including it, i'm getting only the first record it finds and none other

Please advise on what i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, unique would always give only one record, I solved it by using groupBy instead.

```
$availableOperators = DB::table('operator')
            ->join('job','operator.OperatorId', '=', 'job.OperatorId')
            ->where('operator.available',1)
            ->orderBy('job.JobId','desc')
            ->groupBy('job.OperatorId')
            ->get();
```